# Aparecer uma div com hover

Tags: html, css, div, css-hover

Estou fazendo um projeto e tenho que fazer aparecer um ícone, em cada link do menu quando passar o mouse. Pensei em fazer com `JavaScript` mas não tenho muita experiencia, então resolvi fazer com `CSS`, alguém pode me ajudar?
Obrigado.

```
<div id="navbar" class="navbar-collapse collapse">
   <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right menu">
      <li><a href="#who-we-are" rel="quem-somos">Quem Somos</a></li>
      <li><a href="#what-we-do" rel="o-que-fazemos">O Que Fazemos</a></li>
      <li><a href="#portfolio" rel="portfolio">Portfolio</a></li>
      <li><a href="#customers" rel="clientes">Clientes</a></li>
      <li><a class="margin" href="#contatc" rel="contato">Contato</a></li>
   </ul>
</div>
```

Comment: Mostre o código que já tem

Comment: Este é o codigo:

Comment: <div id="navbar" class="navbar-collapse collapse">
<ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right menu">
<li><a href="#who-we-are" rel="quem-somos">Quem Somos</a></li>
<li><a href="#what-we-do" rel="o-que-fazemos">O Que Fazemos</a></li>
<li><a href="#portfolio"  rel="portfolio">Portfolio</a></li>
                                    <li><a href="#customers"  rel="clientes">Clientes</a></li>
                                    <li><a class="margin" href="#contatc" rel="contato">Contato</a></li>
                                </ul>
                            </div>

Comment: Você está usando Boostrap?

Comment: Sim estou, quero fazer aparecer os icones do Bootstrap.

Answer (score 3):

Acho que a maneira mais facil é assim:

```css
.nav li a .glyphicon {
  display:none;
}
.nav li a:hover .glyphicon {
  display: inline;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-1q8mTJOASx8j1Au+a5WDVnPi2lkFfwwEAa8hDDdjZlpLegxhjVME1fgjWPGmkzs7" crossorigin="anonymous">

<div id="navbar" class="navbar-collapse">
   <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right menu">
     <li><a href="#who-we-are" rel="quem-somos">Quem Somos <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-user"></span></a></li>
     <li><a href="#what-we-do" rel="o-que-fazemos">O Que Fazemos <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-pencil"></span></a></li>
     <li><a href="#portfolio" rel="portfolio">Portfolio <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-list-alt"></span></a></li>
     <li><a href="#customers" rel="clientes">Clientes <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-globe"></span></a></li>
     <li><a class="margin" href="#contatc" rel="contato">Contato <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-phone-alt"></span></a></li>
   </ul>
</div>
```

Note que retirei a classe collapse da `#navbar` só para que desse para ver aqui

Answer (score 2):

Bom dia!

Há várias maneiras de se fazer isso. Já que você não tem experiência com JavaScript, a maneira mais fácil de fazer com CSS é com o pseudo-elemento ::before.

No seu caso, ficaria assim:

```
a:hover::before {
  content: url('http://www.famfamfam.com/lab/icons/mini/icons/icon_accept.gif');
  margin: 0 10px;
  position: relative;
  top: 3px;
}
```

Espero ter ajudado!